# How to "load" an encrypted (AES-256) PDF file in mmap() fashion using Quartz?

Tags: ios, pdf, encryption, openssl, quartz-graphics

Yes, I know this question is kind of a mouthful of everything...

I have a PDF file on disk, which is encrypted (AES-256, using CommonCrypto/OpenSSL).
I'd like to render the PDF using Quartz' CGPDF... functions and found it's possible to create a CGPDFDocument with a CGDataProvider.

I'm wondering whether it's possible to create callbacks for the CGDataProvider, to decrypt and load only the blocks in memory that Quartz' PDF renderer needs. I'd rather not write the decrypted file to disk from a security/privacy perspective.

Any ideas?

Hopefully I can start an "enlighted" trial & error with the input of stackoverflow's community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did eventually is use the `CGDataProviderCreateDirect` API and implemented the C callbacks to decrypt parts of the encrypted PDF data, which was loaded using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:]` (which uses mmap() under the hood). This allowed us to render huge encrypted PDFs and having short loading times and low memory usage.

Comment: I'd be interested in some sample code of the implementation. Especially the callbacks and block alignment for the decryption process. Thanks!

Comment: Are you still active here? Could you possibly provide some source code? And if not, at least give some hints how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's small enough, you can just keep it in an NSData - decrypt it on the fly and store it in memory. If it's larger, things are more difficult. Ultimately, people also can decrypt your binary and extract the AES key out of it.

PDF's password protection may add a *small* layer of security, but it's also very easy to circumvent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot about my question, we had already figured out an answer ourselves. Thanks anyway!